# Can't run eclipse on netbook MSi wind! HELP

Tags: eclipse, windows-installer

I just got this MSI wind netbook and tried to run eclipse on it. I installed JDK6 on the netbook already. Whenever I open eclipse there is nothing show up on the screen except a "warning sound" that alerts. What is the problem here?

ps.I just started learning java.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the Eclipse starter program can't find where you installed Java. Since Eclipse is a Java program, it needs a JRE installed (comes with the JDK typically) to run. Assuming you're running Windows on your MSI Wind, check to make sure the java executable is on your path in your computer environment settings (windows key + printscreen button, or windows key + pause button are the shortcuts to open the computer properties dialog if I remember correctly. Then go to advanced).

You can test if java is on the path by opening a cmd.exe shell window and typing 'java'. If it says it cannot find java, then you need to fix the path.

See this link for additional troubleshooting details: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99010.html

Comment: I went to check the path and they are correct. When I tried to run cmd.exe and typed in "java" it says error: could not open D:\....

Comment: Either add D:\<whatever your path is to the folder containing java.exe> to your system environment variables or reinstall the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reinstalling the JDK. Perhaps having it on a different disk than the default (D: versus C:) is causing some trouble? It certainly isn't a problem with the hardware, I'm running Eclipse on Windows on an MSI Wind.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Add/Remove programs" in the control panel to remove the java versions you have installed.

Then visit "java.com" and use it to install Java, and verify that it is working.  You do not need more than that to use Eclipse.